# MVVMLight Business Application?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light, business-application

I would like to create a new Silverlight Business Application, that is using the MVVM Light. Which way to go: Create the business app with Visual Studio, and manually add all the references and files I need for MVVM, or the other way: create project using MVVMLight template, and add the navigation and files to make it "business app"?
Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a matter of what you prefer.

I dont know anything about MVVM Light, but after I create a buisness application I delete some stuff (like the navigation layout) because I dont like them.

So I think that you should choose whatever way you like. In the end the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from scratch, it's hard to see any reason why you wouldn't start with the MVVMLight project.

But the differences are trivial anyway, so you could always flip a coin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi think that's depending on what features do you want to use with the MVVMLite. There are different assemblies that for referencing. Such as if your app just use basic functionality, we can just reference GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4. If you want to use EventToCommand, you can only referent GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4 and System.Windows.Interactivity etc. I prefer reference the assemblies my self for just as the name of "MVVMLite", I want to keep my app "lite" too. Hope it helps.